# Is there a meaning of the word "save" that is a synonym for to "write" or "draw"?

Tags: synonyms

[image: confusing third point]

I'm very confused by the third point about saved flipchart cards. I'm not native and I'm very curious whether it's correct or not.

Comment: It's possible that the intended meaning was *cards, notes, notebooks which you wished to save*, with the implication that any such materials you have not taken with you will be thrown away.  But that's a guess.  It's not obvious.

Answer (score 2):

"Save" doesn't mean "write" or "draw", no.

The wording of the point you asked about is clumsy, but what is meant is that users of the room must take any used flipchart pages and other notes with them if they want to save them from being thrown away after they leave.

Signs of that nature are common in training or conference rooms that may be used by many different groups. Such facilities may provide users with basic stationery items such as pens, notebooks, and (blank) flipcharts. The third point under the "Remember" heading talks about provision of such items. Users are supposed to leave the room tidy, but if they do leave material behind facility staff will throw it away when preparing the room for the next group.

Answer (score 0):

A flip chart is most commonly a type of visual aid where a ((large) in the case of room size presentations) pad of paper is used to write on for the purpose of illustrating the presentation.

The odd verbage most likely comes from the background of the signs author.

I would guess that some flip charts are used for emphatic and personalized illustration, thus wouldn't be used over again in the next similar presentation.

The other type of "saved" or "pre-made" flip chart could be in reference to obviously commercial marketing material that would be re-used with each individual presentation.

So.....the author of the sign is most likely someone that works at a banquet/conference facility and has seen many of both.

Also I agree, the meaning of the sign to me is..... take it with you or it's getting tossed out.